# Adding two binary arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, binary

How can I add two binary arrays(8 bits) and store the result in a third binary array in visual studio 2010 - C++ .
Example : A=00100011   B=11011100   the result_array=11111111

I tried doing that using this to convert B (have decimal value) into binary: 
std::string binary2 = std::bitset<8>(B).to_string();

but when I added the two binary array and storing them into third integer array ,the third array didn't take any value results from the adding operation and still having the default value (which is 00000000)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: If the inputs were both 00000001 what output would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the binary arrays boolean arrays and work from the back:

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        bool a[8]={0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1};
        bool b[8]={1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0};
        bool c[8];

        bool remainder=false;
        for(int x=7;x>=0;x--)
        {
            unsigned sum=0;
            if(remainder)++sum;
            if(a[x])++sum;
            if(b[x])++sum;
            if(sum%2==1)c[x]=true;
            else c[x]=false;
            if(sum>1)remainder=true;
            else remainder=false;
        }
        for(unsigned x=0;x<8;++x)
        {
            std::cout << c[x];
            if(x!=7)std::cout << ",";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your desired result is bitwise manipulation (as in):

```
 10101011 
+11011100
=11111111
```

Then you need to use bitwise or (`|`)

```
uint8_t a = 0x23;
uint8_t b = 0xDC;

uint8_t c = a | b;
```

If you want to do simple addition, such as:

```
 00000001 
+00000011
=00000100
```

Then that is just addition.

```
uint8_t a = 1;
uint8_t b = 2;

uint8_t c = a + b;
```

Comment: 00100011 & 11011100 is 00000000. Should be `|` (bitwise or) to obtain 11111111

Comment: It's not clear whether the OP wants `0x01 + 0x01` to be `0x01` or `0x10`. If the latter, then your suggestion won't work.

Comment: Two good comments.  In the OP's question he states that the desired output is `0xFF` (Which isn't actually addition, but bitwise or).

Comment: @Chad - it might be addition, the example is unclear

Comment: You're right.  Jumped the gun on the answer in this case.  So I've just given examples of both.